# Java Camel Netty TCP consumer only receives 1024 bytes

Tags: java, tcp, apache-camel, netty

I am using latest version of Camel and Netty with spring and have below definition:

```
<bean id="transformIncoming" class="com.hugin.camel.transform.IncomingMessageTransformer"/>
<from uri="netty4:tcp://127.0.0.1:8888?allowDefaultCodec=false&amp;encoder=#byteArrayEncoder"/>

<route>
<transform>
  <method ref="transformIncoming" method="process"></method>
</transform>
```

I defined a class to handle incoming tcp requests:

```
@Component
public class IncomingMessageTransformer implements Processor {

public void process(Exchange in) throws Exception {
    Message inm = in.getIn();
    byte[] buf = inm.getBody(byte[].class);
```

My problem is that regardless of the size of the incoming message, the buf variable is never more than 1024 bytes so my request is truncated.

According to the components definition receiveBufferSize is supposed to be 65536 bytes. How can I handle large requests?

Comment: What do you mean by "message"? Are you using some kind of message protocol? Where do you think is the code to receive a message?

Answer (score 0):

The `receiveBufferSize` property is only used in an UDP consumer, to configure the `SO_RCVBUF` socket option. It's not used in a TCP endpoint.

You should not rely on camel to implement your protocol: Without a proper decoder, a message is sent for each tcp frame, and you can't have a guarantee on the frame size.

You should implement your protocol in Netty, and generate objects which are then handled by camel. Netty have all the tools you need to recompose your protocol over a tcp stream.